# Is RTMPT supported in iOS?

Tags: objective-c

I am having a hard time to find a sample project that relates to RTMPT streamer that supposed to be build/run in iOS. So I thought there's a possibility that there's none at all. I saw some post of others that RTMP is not supported in iOS, is that true? I hope to get some responses and a bit of help too where can I get some samples if there is. I really want to see already runnable codes.

Answer (score -1):

As sanika Kulshreshtha states in [this forum thread](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/949067):

> RTMP is indeed supported on iOS. Are you trying to stream H.264 video?
>   In that case, you will have to use FMS 4.5.
>   http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashmediaserver/articles/stream-ondemand-flash-and-ios.html
>   should help. Some methods and events of Netstream class are not
>   supported on iOS. Check out
>   http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#play()
>   for reference.

Comment: I've added proper attribution here, but please do that in the future when copying material from other sites.